# How to encode password that hased by DefaultPasswordHasher() in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, hash

[image]

In my project, the password is hashed and saved in the database, but how can I get the origin password if I forgot the password?

Comment: Please do not use images for text information

Answer (score 2):

You can't, that's the whole point of using a hash.

If someone forgot their password, then they should set a new one, ie you should implement some form of password reset functionality accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have it ! If user forgot his password, you can send him a link to create a new one (with questions to check his identity).

Comment: Your answer is not fundamentally new from the existing one.